# Android Signature key differences between Old and New PC

Tags: android, key, signature

```
An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed
```

I had developed an inhouse app years back on an old PC and had deployed it. Now I got a new PC, that I used to work on some `upgrades`, but when I tried to `upgrade` the app on `android devices`, I got the above error message.

If I `uninstall` the old version, I am able to `install the upgrade`.  But unfortunately I won't be able to `uninstall` and `reinstall` on re`mote devices`.

I think that if I copy the upgrades back to the old PC and `regenerate` an `APK`, that might work, but **is there any way I can copy the `signature keys` from the old PC to the new one and make the installation work**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will help

The automatically generated key is called the debug `key/certificate`.

You should generate a new key can just copy it over to both your devices. The only negative of this is your builds process is longer as you need a manual steps.

The other option is to copy over the debug key from one of the systems.

You will find the keys in a folder names .android in your home directory in Linux & user directory in Windows

Tip: Never loose the certificate once you push an app to the market.

In Unix like os the debug key is located by default in `~/.android/debug.keystore`